# Comparar cadenas utilizando STRING_SPLIT SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día, tengo una tabla donde se almacena una cadena la cual tendrá unos códigos separados por coma ejemplo: `'1,2,3,5'`.

En una consulta envió por parámetro una cadena de la misma manera con códigos separados por comas.

Como comparo que los códigos de la cadena enviada por el parámetro existan en la columna cuando consulte la tabla.

Anteriormente estaba usando `STRING_SPLIT` ya que antes solo se almacenaba un código en la tabla de la BD.

```
select * from Alertas ALRT where ALRT.CodigoPerfil in STRING_SPLIT(@parametro_codigos',')
```

Pero ahora necesito comparar que de los códigos enviados por el parámetros exista alguno en la cadena almacenada en la columna CodigoPerfil de la tabla.

Había pensado en algo como lo siguiente :

```
 select * from Alertas ALRT where STRING_SPLIT(ALRT.CodigoPerfil, ',') in STRING_SPLIT(@parametro_codigos',')
```

Pero me marca error de sintaxis.

Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como `STRING_SPLIT()` regresa una tabla, no lo puedes comparar como un simple valor escalar. Para compararlos podemos usar la operación `INTERSECT` dentro de una función `EXISTS()`.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Alertas(
    CodigoPerfil varchar(100)
);
INSERT INTO Alertas
VALUES( '1,2,3'), ( '4,5,6'), ( '7,8,9');

DECLARE @parametro_codigos varchar(100) = '1,4';

 SELECT * 
 FROM Alertas ALRT 
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT css.value
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(ALRT.CodigoPerfil, ',') css
                INTERSECT
                SELECT pss.value
                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@parametro_codigos, ',') pss);
```

Comment: Había pensado en el EXISTS pero lo del INTERSECT no lo tenia en mente, me funciono perfectamente. Gracias!!